# Spring OpenSessionInViewFilter and sessionFactory bean not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to add a OpenSessionInViewFilter in my Spring MVC application because accessing a collections in my Thymeleaf templates resulted in a LazyInitializationException. This is what I have:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ApplicationContext.class);
        rootContext.setDisplayName("Test");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
                servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = servletContext.addFilter("openSessionInViewFilter", OpenSessionInViewFilter.class);
        filter.setInitParameter("singleSession", "true");
        filter.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "dispatcher");

    }

}
```

And:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("test.model")
public class ApplicationContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public StringToCompany stringToCompany;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/**");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/js/**");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/images/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(stringToCompany);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionBean sessionBean() {
        return new SessionBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ...
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource( dataSource() );
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan( new String[ ] { "test.model" } );
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter( vendorAdapter );
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties( this.additionalProperties() );
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                this.entityManagerFactory().getObject() );
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        ...
        return properties;
    }

}
```

This results in

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
```

I was hoping it would be as simple as adding this:

```
@Bean
public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    return new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
}
```

but that causes a while bunch of

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;
```

I finally tried changing AnnotationSessionFactoryBean to LocalSessionFactoryBean (Hibernate 4) but that gave me

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Can anyone help me integrate OpenSessionInViewFilter into my current setup? I'm trying not to use xml.

Comment: Don't use the `OpenSessionInViewFilter` use the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` .

Comment: `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Don't use OpenSessionInViewFilter or OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - fully populate a DTO for the front-end instead of passing persistent JPA entities to the front-end. You are currently letting your UI dictate your database access patterns.

Comment: Can you please provide the final answer for this?  I'd like to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter in Spring 4

```
public class WebContextInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
{
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(Application.class);
    rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = servletContext.addFilter("openEntityManagerInViewFilter", OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.class);
    filter.setInitParameter("singleSession", "true");
    filter.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "dispatcher");

    /**
     * Add Spring ContextLoaderListener
     */
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or add OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter in Spring 4 in the web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```